# Require.JS different baseUrls in prod versus development

Tags: requirejs

In production, I'm using CloudFlare as a CDN for my assets so the urls will be

//something.com/javascripts/app.js, etc

In development, everything should just come from the base url of the site, so just /javascripts..

I'm using a build.js file and r.js to optimize and combine my assets before pushing...

Whats the best way to multiplex between these two based on environments.. I have a variable set from the client application in JS that is the correct base url to use..

I've tried setting baseUrl to the CDN in build.js but this just causes a filesystem error (suprisingly)...

I've also tried using the variable I mentioned earlier to get the value to change on the fly, but this breaks r.js's build process...

Thoughts?

Comment: you know that r.js will not download from a CDN, right?

Comment: sorry, took me a minute to figure out your question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a different paths config in your build.js config for the optimizer. Everything else can stay the same (but I don't think you need that variable).

```
paths: {
 app: '//something.com/javascripts/app.js'
}
```